# Laravel отношения одной таблицы к нескольким

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Есть таблица, к примеру users и есть n количество таблиц имеющих поле user_id. Можно ли в одном методе описать отношение таблицы users к остальным таблицам?

Comment: Зачем? это ж бред, как ты к ним потом планируешь тогда обращаться ?

Comment: @Orange_shadow ответ на миллион, спрашивают можно ли, а ты отвечаешь вопросом, зачем и как.

Answer (score 1):

По хорошему так не стоит делать. В дальнейшем возникнут конфликты при использовании такого метода определения отношений, особенно при масштабировании приложения. Восспользуйтесь стандартным описанием отношений между таблицами БД в моделях.
https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/eloquent-relationships
В модели user для каждой таблицы имеющей user_id прописывайте тип отношений с этой таблицей, в модели таблиц имеющих связь с user, соответственно прописывайте тип отношений с этой таблицей.